# Inserting embeded code in database?

Tags: asp.net

In my application I am trying to insert the embedded (video) into database, but it is giving error like this. I am using stored procedure for inserting.

```
Server Error in '/embeded' Application.
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (txtEmbed=" <object width="150" ...").
Description: Request Validation has detected a potentially dangerous client input value, and processing of the request has been aborted. This value may indicate an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. You can disable request validation by setting validateRequest=false in the Page directive or in the configuration section. However, it is strongly recommended that your application explicitly check all inputs in this case.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (txtEmbed=" <object width="150" ...").
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

looks like you didn't even bother to do basic search:

http://www.google.ru/search?q=A+potentially+dangerous+Request.Form+value+was+detected+from+the+client

Comment: is it good process to store the embeded code in database or is there any different process